# A return value cannot be used in this context

Tags: sql-server

I have written a function that returns 1 if the date difference is already greater than or equal to 30.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @flag int
DECLARE @isactive bit
DECLARE @date  Datetime

SET @flag = 0

SELECT @isactive = [m_isactive] 
FROM dbo.rms_month_email 
WHERE m_id = 3

SELECT @date = [m_createddate] 
FROM dbo.rms_month_email 
WHERE m_id = 3

IF (@isactive = 1 AND DATEDIFF(dd,@date,GETDATE()) = 30)
   SET  @flag = 1

RETURN @flag
```

but it has generated this error:

> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

What does this mean?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_isBonus]
(@m_id AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @flag AS int
    DECLARE @isactive AS bit
    DECLARE @date AS Datetime

    SET @flag = 0

    SELECT @isactive = [m_isactive] FROM dbo.rms_month_email WHERE m_id = @m_id
    SELECT @date = [m_createddate] FROM dbo.rms_month_email WHERE m_id = @m_id

    IF (@isactive = 1 AND DATEDIFF(dd,@date,GETDATE()) = 30)
         SET @flag = 1

    RETURN @flag
END
GO
```

This is the whole code for this function.

Comment: Provide all your function with `CREATE FUNCTION Name...`. Looks like you have incorrect syntax.

Comment: I don't see the function's definition here.. If you want to test the body of a function in a batch, use `SELECT @flag` instead of `RETURN`.

Comment: I see no errors in this function. Voting for close

Comment: You can also fetch more than 1 value in select statement, so you don't really need to access the table twice.

Answer (score 12):

You need to understand that `Return` works only inside a function or stored procedure. If you are not using it inside a function or stored procedure then it is just a batch of select statements. So you need to use `select` instead of `return`.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b9e8)**

**EDIT:**

Your edit after you modified it as a function works perfectly fine.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b9e8)**

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `CASE` instead of `IF` and remove `SET @flag = 0`:

```
USE [petc_rms]
GO

 /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_isBonus]    Script Date:     9/29/2015 3:35:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_isBonus]
(
 -- Add the parameters for the function here

    @m_id AS INT

)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @flag AS int
DECLARE @isactive AS bit
DECLARE @date AS Datetime


    SELECT @isactive = [m_isactive] FROM dbo.rms_month_email WHERE m_id = @m_id
    SELECT @date = [m_createddate] FROM dbo.rms_month_email WHERE m_id = @m_id

    SET @flag = CASE WHEN @isactive = 1 AND DATEDIFF(dd,@date,GETDATE()) = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    

Return @flag

END

GO
```

Check about how to [**CREATE FUNCTION**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Comment: @IamGlads try to check now.

Comment: Thank you so much! so I got a problem in the flag then. thank you again.

Comment: @IamGlads do not forget to check It as correct answer for future users. To make It you can mark `V` in top-left of answer.

Comment: excuse me, how is this an improvement ? Seems to me this is doing exactly the same